# Is there any harm in overriding an "empty" virtual destructor with another one?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, virtual-inheritance, virtual-destructor

Say I am inheriting from a class with an "empty" virtual destructor:

```cpp
// base.h
class Base {
 public:
  // ...
  virtual ~Base();
};

// base.cc
Base::~Base() {}
```

If I don't need to do any explicit work in the derived class's destructor, is there any harm in adding another "empty" one like bleow?

```
// derived.h
class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  // ...
  ~Derived() override;
};

// derived.cc
Derived::~Derived() {}
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568322/why-the-virtual-destructor-in-derived-class-is-empty) says it's not *necessary*, but is there any harm?

Comment: Except for the cost of the out-of-line definition, no, there's no harm.

Comment: Treat the programmer that someday will have to maintain your code as a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.  And there won't be any harm.

Comment: If we ignore the compilation error caused by your `~Derived` , there will be no harm. But then again - the `~Base` doesn't compile either so at least it didn't get that much worse.

Comment: Perhaps the worry is that ~Base() won't be called unless ~Derived() explicitly invokes it (i.e. similar to the way other virtual method overrides work).  If so, don't worry about that -- all destructors will always be called no matter what, so there is no possibility that the subclass destructor will "hide" the base class destructor and e.g. cause a resource leak.

Comment: @KerrekSB Funnily, there is a bigger cost for inline definition.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: There's costs for both ways, different enough that it's tricky to call one "bigger" than the other.  Compilation memory vs linker-inlining-complexity

Answer (score 0):

> is there any harm in adding another "empty" one like bleow?

Every translation unit that inlines the constructor of `Derived` will have to generate an out-of-line copy of the inline destructor to put its address in the virtual table of `Derived`. The linker throws away the duplicate virtual tables, however, the out-of-line copies of the destructor stay, along with its debug info.

Making the destructor out-of-line prevents the above code duplication and makes your object files, executables and shared libraries smaller.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Pretty much any linker made in the last 20 years can also inline out-of-line funtions as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck: True, but misleading. (1) Link-Time Optimization is opt-in, and some large libraries require a very large amount of resources for it and (2) Link-Time Optimization only solve the issue for the library containing the definition, and not any of its clients, when linking dynamically.